# Google Analytics - Don't view as unique pages

Tags: google-analytics

I have a url similar to this

/widgets/view/13031800

In the google analytics settings you can have it exclude url paramaters, but I can't figure out how to have it look at all

/widgets/view/  pages as one page.  I don't need each one to be unique.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there is not an easy answer to this.  You can...

- change what is passed in your _trackPageview calls on your page(s) to exclude the number
- create a filter in the interface to strip off the number

Neither one of these solutions will retroactively apply (will not change data you already got).

Only way to see it for current data is to export your data to excel or whatever and do some manual work on it, like strip off the numbers and sum up the page views and remove duplicates sort of thing.

Comment: thanks for the response, I think i will try changing what is passed in the trackPageview call.